# How can I tell what kind of baseboard heater I have installed?

Tags: heating

I assumed the baseboard heaters in my rented apartment were electric since there is an electricity breaker that effectively turns off the heating. However, after looking at my utility bill, I think it may actually use gas as well.

How can I tell what kind of heater it is? Here is a photo of it.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's most likely hot water (hydronic) - the heat source might well be gas (and will be a lot cheaper than electric if so, in most places). The breaker probably shuts off the power to the boiler.

As for "how do I tell for sure?" ask your landlord.

There is a fairly small possibility that it **could** be steam.